# Remove space between image and view in collaut component react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I want render some text and an image inside a Marker component (react-native-maps) but for the image I have a problem. There is a space between image and the View1 and I don't know why. I want remove the space.

This is what I have:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keYid.jpg)

and the space that I want to remove

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHQhR.jpg)

this is my code:

```
<Callout tooltip >
              <View style={styles.bubble} >
                <View style={styles.view1} >
                   <Text style={styles.text}>name</Text>
                   <Text style={styles.text}>description</Text>
                </View>
                  
                    <View style={styles.view2} >
                       <Text>
                         <Image  source={require('./assets/photo/mare.jpg')}
                          style={styles.image} resizeMode="cover" />
                      </Text>
                    </View>
               </View>

            </Callout>
```

and the style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   bubble:{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection:'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 6,
    borderColor: 'white',
    width: 200,
    height: 250,
  },
text: {
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: 20,
  color: 'black',
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  paddingTop:1 
},
image: {
    width: 160,
    height: 160,
  },
 view1:{
    flex:3,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  view2:{
    flex:7,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'flex-start'
}
});
```

Someone can help me? Very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using flex: 3 on view1 and flex: 7 on view2.

This means that 30% of the total space is used in the top view and 70% on the bottom view. Have a play around with those values to change how the available space is shared between both views.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tryed to change flex but image is cut and the space remains